# Contact initialization taking long time in DXA 2.0 Java application

Tags: dxa, web8.5, dxa-java, dxa-2.0, audience-manager

We are using SDL 8.5 and DXA 2.0 Java for our website. We are using inprocess approach of audience manager in our website recently we have noticed while initializing any contact which does not exist in audience manager subscription database is taking around 7 sec also we have noticed that cd_staorage.config file keeps getting updated by the java process.Below is code for initialize contact

```
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            com.tridion.marketingsolution.profile.Contact contact = null;
            try {
                contact = new com.tridion.marketingsolution.profile.Contact(new String[]{"xyzp", "test@test.com"});
            } catch(Exception e) {
                out.println("test contact initialize time: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime));
            }
```

**CD_STORAGE.CONFIG**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Configuration Version="8.5">
    <Global>
        <Storages>
            <StorageBindings>
                <Bundle src="AudienceManagerDAOBundle.xml"/>
            </StorageBindings>
            <!-- Profile DB Oracle -->
            <Storage Class="com.tridion.storage.persistence.JPADAOFactory" Id="profiledbOracle" Type="persistence" dialect="ORACLESQL">
                <Pool CheckoutTimeout="120" IdleTimeout="120" MonitorInterval="60" Size="5" Type="jdbc"/>
                <DataSource Class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource">
                    <Property Name="driverType" Value="thin"/>
                    <Property Name="networkProtocol" Value="tcp"/>
                    <Property Name="URL" Value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS_LIST =(ADDRESS =(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=192.168.10.10)(PORT=1831)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=SDLPCDB)(SERVER=SHARED)))"/>
                    <Property Name="user" Value="test_sm"/>
                    <Property Name="password" Value="sm_2018"/>
                </DataSource>
            </Storage>
            <!-- Tracking DB Oracle -->
            <Storage Class="com.tridion.storage.persistence.JPADAOFactory" Id="trackingdbOracle" Type="persistence" dialect="ORACLESQL">
                <Pool CheckoutTimeout="120" IdleTimeout="120" MonitorInterval="60" Size="5" Type="jdbc"/>
                <DataSource Class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource">
                    <Property Name="driverType" Value="thin"/>
                    <Property Name="networkProtocol" Value="tcp"/>
                    <Property Name="URL" Value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS_LIST =(ADDRESS =(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=192.168.10.10)(PORT=1831)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=SDLPCDB)(SERVER=SHARED)))"/>
                    <Property Name="user" Value="test_PS"/>
                    <Property Name="password" Value="test_2018"/>
                </DataSource>
            </Storage>
        </Storages>
    </Global>
    <ItemTypes cached="true" defaultStorageId="profiledbOracle">
        <Item storageId="profiledbOracle" typeMapping="AudienceManagerProfile"/>
        <Item storageId="trackingdbOracle" typeMapping="AudienceManagerTracking"/>
    </ItemTypes>
    <License Location="D:/SDLWeb/Licenses/cd_licenses.xml"/>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: Have you considered using the DXA Audience Manager Module?

Comment: What is the reason for using "in-process approach" rather that using the AM microservices?